# Getting data using ajax (async loading?) in python

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to scrape some financial data using python (url is http://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-finder). It's a list of 2,164 exchange traded funds. I'm looking to get all of the data in the classification tab. It almost looks like an excel spreadsheet embedded on the web page. There are 109 "screens" of data. I have a line of code:

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text). This gets data from the first screen, but doesn't get data from the other 108. How would I get the data from the other 108 "screens"?

I've seen some code where I can write a loop as the page changes, but the url does not have any page information in it and does not change as I move from one screen of data to another.

I haven't been coding for a long time and scraping data like this is new to me. I've been looking up ajax and asynchronous loading, but I need someone to push me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Here's all of my code. At this point I'm trying to scrape the information that I need and put it in a sqlite table.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as db
import requests

# create empty list to store our data scraped
data_list = []

url = 'http://www.etf.com/etfanalytics/etf-finder'

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)
# df holds multiple DataFrames - index [5] is the classification tab.

df[5].columns = ['Ticker', 'Fund Name', 'Asset Class', 'Strategy', 'Region', 'Geography', 'Category', 'Focus', 'Niche', 'Inverse', 'Leveraged', 'ETN', 'Underlying Index', 'Index Provider', 'Selection Criteria', 'Weighting Scheme', 'Active per SEC']

data_list.append(df[5])

# create a "master" data frame which concatenates all the relevant information together
masterFrame = pd.concat(data_list)

# create a connection to our previously created SQLite database
# use the path and name which corresponds to your local database
cnx = db.connect(r'C:\Users\madan\sqlite\etfs.db')
cur = cnx.cursor()

# remove table if already exists and any data it contains
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etftable;')

# create the table within the database
sql = '''CREATE TABLE etftable ('Ticker' TEXT, 'Fund Name' TEXT, 'Asset Class' TEXT, 'Strategy' TEXT, 'Region' TEXT, 'Geography' TEXT, 'Category' TEXT, 'Focus' TEXT, 'Niche' TEXT, 'Inverse' TEXT, 'Leveraged' TEXT, 'ETN' TEXT, 'Underlying Index' TEXT, 'Index Provider' TEXT, 'Selection Criteria' TEXT, 'Weighting Scheme' TEXT, 'Active per SEC' TEXT)'''

cur.execute(sql)

# append the data
masterFrame.to_sql(name='etftable', con=cnx, if_exists='append', index=False)

cnx.close()
```

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to scrape the data and put it in a sqlite table.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific page, you can only get to the next page with JavaScript. Examining the code, I see that there is an API end-point:

```
http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-funds-api//-aum/40/20/1
```

The `40` means start from the 40th record, `20` is get the next 20 records, and this returns an easy-to-parse JSON record.

However, trying this in Chrome fails; there are a bunch of headers and cookies that perhaps need to be set up first before you can access the API, and there might also be a Same Origin rule that prevents you calling the API from outside.

One possible solution (I've not tried at all) would be to do [remote control of Chrome](https://github.com/iiSeymour/chromote) to activate the JavaScript buttons, and perhaps [intercept the network messages to grab the replies](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Network).

To sum up: standard scraping tools as I previously suggested will not work; you probably need to get into the browser's guts and capture the data transfers.

Or just pay (probably a lot of) money for access to a commercial API!